# Count number of transitions in each row of a Numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

I have a 2D boolean array

`a=np.array([[True, False,  True,  False,  True],[True , True,  True , True,  True], [True , True ,False, False ,False], [False, True , True,  False,  False], [True , True ,False, True, False]])`

I would like to create a new array, providing count of True-False transitions in each row of this array.

The desired result is count=[2, 0, 1, 1, 2]

I operate with a large numpy array, so I don't apply cycle to browse through all lines.

I tried to adopt available solutions to a 2D array with counting for each line separately, but did not succeed.

Comment: @MichaelSzczesny Please post as answer.

Comment: `(a[:, 1:] & ~a[:, :-1]).sum(1)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a possible solution:

```
b = a.astype(int)
c = (b[:, :-1] - b[:, 1:])
count = (c == 1).sum(axis=1)
```

Result:

```
>>> count
array([2, 0, 1, 1, 2])
```